# Adobe Javascript Signature Lock

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

I am trying to use Adobe Javascript to change the properties of a fillable form text box when a signature is added to a signature block.

A PDF file is created by exporting from Excel into PDF.

An Action is then used to Detect Form Fields which produces 2 text boxes and 2 signature blocks automatically.

The Action then runs this:

```
var f =this.getField("Signature").required = true ;
```

to make the first signature block a required form.

Everything is successful up to this point.

The action then attempts to run this:

```
var f =this.getField("Signature");
var oLock = f.getLock();
oLock.action = "include";
oLock.fields = new Array("Receivers CommentsRow1");
f.setLock(oLock);
```

Which throws up the error

> TypeError: oLock is null
>       4:Batch:Exec

Running directly from the console gives the same error.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/Acro12_MasterBook/JS_API_AcroJS/Field_methods.htm?rhtocid=_6_1_8_31_2_12#TOC_getLockbc-13

```
oLock.action = "include";
```

"include" should be initial caps "Include".